# regular expression to match a string as a two dimensional array of integers

Tags: java, regex, multidimensional-array

I am looking for a regex to recognize strings that could be a two dimensional array of integers that has columns with same length.

for example this is a string that I want to convert it to a two dimensional array:

`0 4 8 4\n9 6 5 7\n9 5 5 1`

which could be :

```
0 4 8 4
9 6 5 7
9 5 5 1
```

So I came up with this:`"(([0-9]+[ \t]?)+(\n|\r)?){1,}"` however it does not check if columns have the same length.
thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: how columns are separated? with a space, a tab, any of them? (in other words, could items contain spaces?)

Comment: `\n` to select rows and `space|tab` for columns @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: Why do you need to use regex? Its uses are far more limited than people often think, and you could just be creating another problem for yourself.

Comment: it is shorter than using loop to validate the string . @ThePcLuddite

Comment: @femchi Maybe the code is shorter, but your it will become less clear and more performance intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with this kind of pattern (add optional CR if needed):

```
(?m)^(?>(?>\\d+([ \\t]|$)(?=.*\\n(\\2?+\\d+\\1)))+\\n(?=\\2$))+.*
```

[demo](http://fiddle.re/d7k4w6) *(click the java button)*

For each item in the first line the lookahead checks if an item in the same column exists in the next line. To know if the columns are the same, the capture group 2 contains an optional self reference `\\2?+`. In this way, the capture group 2 grows each time the "item" group is repeated (and reaches the next column).

details:

```php
(?m) # use the multiline mode
^    # start of the line
(?>  # group for a complete line
    (?> # group for an item
        \\d+ ([ \\t]|$) # a number followed by a space/tab or the end of the line
        (?= # looakead
            .*\\n # reach the next line
            (\\2?+\\d+\\1) # capture group 2
        )
    )+ # repeat the item group
    \\n 
    (?=\\2$) # check if there isn't more columns in the next line
)+ # repeat the line group
.* # match the next line
```

Note: this pattern checks if separators are unique (not repeated) and always the same with `([ \\t]|$)` and `\\1` (in the capture group 2). Leading and trailing white-spaces aren't allowed. But you can write it in a more flexible way:

```
(?m)^(?>[ \\t]*(?>\\d+[ \\t]*(?=.*\\r?\\n(\\1?+\\d+(?:[ \\t]+|[ \\t]*$))))+\\r?\\n(?=\\1$))+.*\\2$))+.*
```

These patterns can be used either with `matches()` to check a whole string or `find()` to find eventual arrays in a larger string.

Comment: Good lord, that's incredible! (+1) Are you able to tell the dimensions from this, or does it just validate that the String resembles a 2d array?

Comment: @Shar1er80: Thanks. No, it only extracts/validates the array, to know the dimensions you must use more conventional ways (these numbers are not written in the text).

Answer (score 2):

### UPDATE

If you wanted to do straight `regex` for validation of a 2d array, you can build patterns that validate specific "x by y" 2d arrays.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "0 4 8 4\n9 6 5 7\n9 5 5 1";

    // Check if the data is either a 2 x 2 - 10 x 10 array
    for (int row = 2; row <= 10; row++) {
        for (int col = 2; col <= 10; col++) {
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(buildPattern(row, col)).matcher(data);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                System.out.printf("Valid %d x %d array%n", row, col);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Invalid 2d array");
}

public static String buildPattern(int row, int col) {
    StringBuilder patternBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < col; c++) {
            patternBuilder.append("\\d+");
            if (c + 1 < col) patternBuilder.append("[ ]");
        }
        if (r + 1 < row) patternBuilder.append("\n");
    }
    return patternBuilder.toString();
}
```

Results:

```
Valid 3 x 4 array
```

### OLD ANSWER

I would do 2 splits.

1. Split to get rows
2. Split to get number of columns from the first row

From there, I would get the number of rows that have the same number of columns as the first row.  If the result of that is equal to the number of rows from split 1, then we know it's a 2d array.  Otherwise, it's a jagged array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "0 4 8 4\n9 6 5 7\n9 5 5 1";

    // Get the rows
    String[] rows = data.split("[\r]?[\n]");

    // Get the number of columns in the first row
    int colCount = rows[0].split(" ").length;

    // Check if all rows have the same number of columns as the first row
    if (Arrays.stream(rows)
            .filter(row -> row.split(" ").length == colCount)
            .count() == rows.length) {
        System.out.println("Valid 2d array");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Jagged array");
    }
}
```

Results:

```
Valid 2d array
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer but I am curious to know if it is possible through using regex.

Comment: I would say that it is, but the pattern would probably have to be set for a specific "x" by "y" array.